# When do we need to re-inherit from an interface that has been implemented by a class from which we are inheriting?

Tags: c#

The compiler does not give any warnings. So it makes me curios. When do we need to re-inherit from an interface that has been implemented by a class from which we are inheriting?

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Any();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Any() => Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}

class Program : Foo, IFoo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo ifoo = new Program();
        ifoo.Any();

        Foo foo = new Program();
        foo.Any();


        Program program = new Program();
        program.Any();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect an error / warning?

Comment: @mjwills: similar to hiding, the compiler warns us.

Comment: What is there for it you warn you _about_ though? What are you concerned could go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When do we need to re-inherit from an interface that has been
>   implemented by a class from which we are inheriting?

It is perfectly valid to do that, and then explicitly implement `IFoo` in `Program` to have a different implementation.

An example is:

```
using System;

interface IFoo
{
    void Any();
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public void Any() => Console.WriteLine("Foo");
}

class Program : Foo, IFoo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IFoo ifoo = new Program();
        ifoo.Any();

        Foo foo = new Program();
        foo.Any();


        Program program = new Program();
        program.Any();
    }

    void IFoo.Any() => Console.WriteLine("Program");
}
```

This will output:

```
Program
Foo
Foo
```

Granted, this is *unusual* and rarely used. But it is one example of why it can be helpful for the compiler to *allow* the class to *effectively override* the interface implementation.

Comment: `program.Any();` are you sure this will print `Foo`

Comment: Can you please explain this behavior.

Comment: The first one writes `Program` since `Program` told it to via interface implementation. The second writes `Any` since that is what `Foo`'s `Any` method does. The third writes `Any` since `Program` lacks an `Any` method (it _looks_ like it has an `Any` method, but it doesn't really - Program's `Any` method is only for explicit interface implementation).

Comment: well, it may be useful when you do not have control over the `Foo` class and can't make the `Any` method virtual. However having different results from `Foo foo = new Program();` and `IFoo ifoo = new Program();` can make developers cry